# The Marx generator circuit isn't working. We are having trouble getting the output

Tags: bjt, 555, homework, proteus

As you can see, we are trying to build a Marx generator using BJT (astable configuration.)

We have a circuit for the Marx generator using a 555 timer which we tried and tested and it works fine.

We are not able to implement the same using BJTs:(

I'm attaching the 555 timer equivalent circuit and the circuit we are trying to build.

**Edit:**
Please see the image I added.  It is a clearer image of the 555 circuit.

BJT circuit:
[image: the one with bjts]

555 circuit:
[image: the one with 555 timer]

555 timer circuit:
[image: 555 timer ckt]

Comment: how is it possible to get an unreadably blurry image with screen capture?

Comment: i'm sorry for the blurred image .I hope i can change it within a short time.Thanks

Comment: Needs more focus. Needs fewer dots too.

Comment: what about now.Is it fine?

Comment: No, they are both awful - home in on one spot and tell me the values you can read. This isn't rocket science to get right. Lose the dots; lose the lines; not needed.

Comment: I'm trying hard to ans ur question..i will get back u soon

Comment: What's not working? Does the astable work on its own ignoring the Marx bit?

Comment: yes astable work on its own.please also see the image i added  of the 555 equivalent ckt

Comment: Why did you add the [tag:ltspice] tag?

Comment: I don't know what gone through my mind.Its proteus (i do my labs in ltspices also).Made a mistake sorry.

Comment: 1N4007 diodes can be pretty slow - what switching frequency did you use?

Comment: 220hz I think.(i really appreciate ur  effort.Thanks)